# How can I print it out in this order: table, bar chart, table ...?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I print it out in this order: table, bar chart, table, bar chart, ...?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 10), 
             columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
for column in df:
    print(df[column].value_counts(normalize=True, bins=10))
    print(df[column].hist(bins=10))
```

It prints all tables first. Then prints one joint bar chart. But I want to mix tables and bar charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by tables? Are you doing `plt.show()` to get your plots?

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column].value_counts(normalize=True, bins=10))
    print(df[column].hist(bins=10))
    plt.show()
```

Shows me the value value_counts with each individual plot. If you do it outside of the loop, the plots would just accumulate it unless you clear them.